# I need to load data from laravel api with paginate in flutter

Tags: laravel, flutter, dart

I am trying to load from a Laravel API with pagination but return null. This is my code

```
Future<List<Post>> getData() async {
    // start get post
    try {
      http.Response response = await http.get(
          "http://iraqdoctors.com/api/stars",
          headers: {"Accept": "application/json"});
      List collection = json.decode(response.body);
      return collection.map((json) => Post.fromJson(json)).toList();
    } catch (e) {
      isLoading = false;
    }
  }
```

and in listview

```
snapshot.data[index].name
```

Comment: Could you please include snippets about your controller function?

Comment: would you please give us more information about your code/implementation?

Comment: In laravel  $doctors = Doctors::where('star','=' , 1 )->paginate(10);         
        return  $doctors;

Comment: In flutter I/chatty  ( 4388): uid=10112(u0_a112) Thread-2 identical 3 lines
I/flutter ( 4388): null